# Why is my Player property in QuestGUI returning null despite initialization in the Game constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization, text-based

I am implementing an text-based game in C#.
In the "Game"-class, I am initializing a player. If this player completes a quest, he would earn some rewards. Therefore, I want to give the initialized player to another class called QuestGUI.

The constructor of the game class:

```
        public Game()
        {
            Item[] initialItems = new Item[]
            {
                new Weapon("Sword", 10),
            };
            main_player = new Player("Omegar", 100, initialItems);

            Quest[] quests = new Quest[]
            {
                new Quest(...);
            };

            QuestHub QuestHub = new QuestHub(quests);
            QuestGUI = new QuestGUI(QuestHub);
            QuestHubGUI = new QuestHubGUI(QuestHub);

            QuestGUI.Player = main_player;
        }
```

Here is what I want to do in the QuestGUI class:

```
                QuestHub.DisplayResult(quest, input);

                Item reward = Player.GenerateItem();
                Player.AddItem(reward);
                Player.ReceiveItemMessage(reward);
```

The constructor of the QuestGUI-class:

```
        public Player Player { get; set; }
        public QuestHub QuestHub { get; set; }

        public QuestGUI(QuestHub questHub)
        {
            QuestHub = questHub;
        }
```

I tried to run what I described above. I expected the program to first display the result of the quest and then give the player a generated item. Instead, I got the following exception:

System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

lb426_test.QuestGUI.Player.get returned null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `main_player` in the `Game` class. In the `QuestGUI` class, you have declared the property `Player`, which is not initialized in the constructor of `QuestGUI`. You have to add the player as a constructor parameter and initialize it.

```
    public Player Player { get; set; }
    public QuestHub QuestHub { get; set; }

    public QuestGUI(QuestHub questHub, Player player)
    {
        QuestHub = questHub;
        Player = player;
    }
```

Then you need to adjust the constructor in the `Game` class to

```
    public Game()
    {
        Item[] initialItems = new Item[]
        {
            new Weapon("Sword", 10),
        };
        main_player = new Player("Omegar", 100, initialItems);

        Quest[] quests = new Quest[]
        {
            new Quest(...);
        };

        QuestHub QuestHub = new QuestHub(quests);
        QuestGUI = new QuestGUI(QuestHub, main_player);
        QuestHubGUI = new QuestHubGUI(QuestHub);

        QuestGUI.Player = main_player;
    }
```